# Is there a way to get rid of the syntax error when I run try and except?

Tags: python-3.x

```
    while True:
      try:
         a = float(input("Enter a number for how long the break between words should be:")
      except ValueError:
          print("YOu haven't entered a number")
```

1. After I execute it:

   ```
    File "main.py", line 7
        except ValueError:
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```
2. Why do I get this error?

Comment: typo: close the parentheses for `float`.

Comment: @BlamelessShoe79 you put indentation of ```2``` in **while** where in **try** you put indentation of ```3``` and ```4``` inside **except**, use ide for correct indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of this line:

```
a = float(input("Enter a number for how long the break between words should be:")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing parenthesis on line 3, your code should read:

```
while True:
  try:
     a = float(input("Enter a number for how long the break between words should be:"))
  except ValueError:
      print("You haven't entered a number")
```